# I removed Macintosh HD from backup disk how do I set it back?

Tags: hard-drive, macbook-pro, backup

I used 2 backup disks , Macintosh HD and Seagate . My macintosh was unable to perform a backup due to lack of space while my Seagate is unable to perform a backup until the first backup is complete. And I happened to remove Macintosh HD from the back up disk and I couldn't set it back because the name Macintosh HD is no longer under the "Available Disk" besides Seagate

[image]

How do I retrieve it back?

Comment: Please open `Disk Utility` in /Applications/Utilities with all drives attached, make a screenshot and add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, now that we have clarified what the issue is, here's how to solve your problem.

1. Open System Preferences
2. Select "Time Machine"
3. Click "Options"
4. Macintosh HD will probably be listed under "Exclude these items from backups:". Click it and click the "-" button below the box and then click "Save"
5. Make sure that Time Machine shows the correct disk in the window (in your case, it should say "**Seagate-3E59C4 TM Backup** - Seagate-3E59C4". It is important to note that "Macintosh HD" will not show up here as it is displaying the disk to be backed up to, not the disk that is being backed up. "Macintosh HD" should never show up when you click "Select Disk..."
6. If you are running a MacBook, plug the MacBook in to power
7. In the menu bar, click the Time Machine icon and select "Back Up Now"

Time Machine should now start backing up to your Seagate drive. If you are still having trouble with Time Machine looking for the disk, then do the following:

1. Click "Select Disk..." in the Time Machine preferences
2. Select "Seagate-3E59C4 TM Backup" under "Backup Disks"
3. Click the "Remove Disk" button. The dialog will prompt you for confirmation and close
4. Click the "Select Backup Disk..." button
5. Select "Seagate-3E59C4 TM Backup" again and click "Use Disk"
6. If your Seagate is password protected, it will ask you for the password

Comment: what if there's no file labelled "TimeMachineDoNotPresent" ? I can't seem to find it

Comment: It seems there was a change in the naming convention. Look for `.com.apple.timemachine.donotpresent` instead. Is the drive plugged in to your Mac directly, or through an AirPort Extreme / Time Capsule?

Comment: it's already in the mac since the day i got it

Comment: Okay, I see where the confusion has come in. The wording in your question made it sound like you were doing a Time Machine backup _to_ a drive called "Macintosh HD", where you are actually backing Macintosh HD, which is your Mac's internal hard drive, to your Seagate drive, am I correct?

Comment: yess ! pardon my poor english

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect the clarification. If this post has answered your question satisfactorily, please could you mark the question as answered so as to move it from the "Unanswered" section. Thanks